# Filter response by email: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have an ionic 3 application, I get data from multiple users, I want to create a page where the user can see his own items, that he added to the website, the only identifier I have is the email.

Service

```
  getMyAds(page, email): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.api_url + page)
      .flatMap((ads: any[]) => {
        if (ads.length > 0) {
          return Observable.forkJoin(
            ads.map((ad: any) => {
              if (ad.email == email) { --> this is causing the problem
                return this.http.get(this.ads_thumb_url + ad.id)
                  .map((res: any) => {
                    let media: any = res;
                    ad.media = media;
                    return ad;
                  });
              }
            })
          );
        }
        return Observable.of([]);
      });
  }
```

`page.ts`

```
 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public renderer: Renderer, public zone: NgZone, public adsProvider: AdsProvider) {
    if (localStorage.getItem('wpIonicToken')) {
      this.localstorageString = localStorage.getItem('wpIonicToken');
      this.user = JSON.parse(this.localstorageString);

      this.loadAds();
    }
  }
  loadAds(infiniteScroll?) {
    this.adsProvider.getMyAds(this.page, this.user.user_email).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.items = this.items.concat(data);
      if (infiniteScroll) {
        infiniteScroll.complete();
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm getting the email from `localStorage` and passing it to `getMyAds()`

`RunTime Error: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable`

I guess I can solve it by rxjs, instead of doing `if ..` but I'm not that good at Rxjs.

I treid filtering from the `page.ts` by checking the data for a given email, it didn't work. Anyhow isn't filtering from the service better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be using .filter as well as .map to create your forkJoin array.

If you do not return anything from Array.map it will still contain an element for that input item, but it will be undefined - therefore some of the items you are attempting to forkJoin over are not observables, which would give the error seen.

This should fix the issue:

```
  getMyAds(page, email): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.api_url + page)
      .flatMap((ads: any[]) => {
        if (ads.length > 0) {
          return Observable.forkJoin(
            ads.filter((ad: any) => ad.email == email).map((ad) => {
                return this.http.get(this.ads_thumb_url + ad.id)
                  .map((res: any) => {
                    let media: any = res;
                    ad.media = media;
                    return ad;
                  });
            })
          );
        }
        return Observable.of([]);
      });
  }
```

Comment: your solution works, but I'm only seeing 8 ads, I know that this user has uploaded more than 300 ads. If I don't filter by email then I can get all the ads. Would you know why this method is returning only 8 ads?

Comment: I have no way of knowing that @Lynob :) have you checked the data being returned from `this.api_url + page` (e.g. in the Network tab of Chrome dev tools) to check that there really are 300 items in the source array with the email address in question? Check (e.g.) for the email address being in a different case, or having spaces before/after - you're doing a simple equality-check on the strings, so it will be case/white-space sensitive.

Comment: it was a whitespace and a lowercase problem, I should create another account to upvote you twice :) you solved two problems thank you!

Comment: No problems - .trim and .toLowerCase on both strings would normalize that out (be careful if there might be nulls...).